# collect distinct nodes and relations from multiple rows

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm writing a query to retrieve nodes and relations from multiple paths :

```
MATCH path=(p:Label)-[*..100]->() 
RETURN [n in nodes(path) | ID(n)] as nodeIds, 
       [n in nodes(path)] as nodes, 
       [r in  relationships(path) | ID(r)] as relationshipIds, 
       [r in  relationships(path) | type(r)] as relationshipTypes, 
       [r in  relationships(path)] as relationships
```

However I have multiple rows (corresponding to each path) with possibly the same data.

I'd like to have one row containing all the distinct `nodeIds`, `relationshipIds`, ...

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I run this query, I don't get duplicate data.  But I can see why you might think there's duplicate data.  First, you could try this:

```
MATCH path=(p:Label)-[*..100]->() 
WITH DISTINCT(path) as path
RETURN [n in nodes(path) | ID(n)] as nodeIds, 
       [n in nodes(path)] as nodes, 
       [r in  relationships(path) | ID(r)] as relationshipIds, 
       [r in  relationships(path) | type(r)] as relationshipTypes, 
       [r in  relationships(path)] as relationships
ORDER BY length(path) LIMIT 1;
```

This would ensure that all paths were distinct, which would mean you couldn't have repeated data, but I think that should already be the case.   Ordering by path length means longest paths go first, and limit 1 means only the longest path.

Anyway, the duplication you're probably seeing is due to paths and path fragments.   Let's say I have `a->b->c`.  Your query will report three paths:

- `a->b->c`
- `a->b`
- `b->c`

Note that's the correct answer.  But in terms of node IDs and relationship IDs, you're going to see a lot of duplication in the result set, because every single node ID will occur at least twice in the results.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But if there a way to collect all these ids in a single row ?

Comment: Collect all of which IDs?  In my example, there are three paths.  There should be three result lines.  What would the single row contain?  Only the longest path?  Which of the three?

Comment: You're right, what I really want is to get all the longest paths.